# What is wrong with my R codes for transforming a wide data frame into the long format?

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose, reshape2

I am running the following `R` codes in `Rstudio` with the aim to convert a wide data frame (called 'merged') into a long one.

```
> merged
          Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
2017 (A) 5980 5341 5890 5596 5753 5470 5589 5545 5749 5938 5844 5356
2017 (P) 5762 5275 5733 5411 5406 4954 5464 5536 5805 5819 5903 5630
```

I'm after the following output:

```
  Description    Month    RN
  2017 (A)       Jan      5980
  2017 (P)       Jan      5762
  2017 (A)       Feb      5341
  2017 (P)       Feb      5275
  ...            ...      ...
```

I have tried the following (but with no success):

```
library(reshape2)
merged_long <- melt(data=merged, 
               id.vars="Description", 
               variable.name="Month",
               value.name="RN")
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error: id variables not found in data: Description
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, the error is quite clear. You don't have a variable called `Description` in your `merged` data frame. It seems that `2017 (A), 2017 (P)` are rownames

Comment: Thanks, I got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @Sotos in the comments, data in the rownames of the `merged` data set is required to uniquely identify an observation in the melted data set. To include the rownames in the melted data set, add the following to your code.

```
merged$Description <- rownames(merged)
```

Then your original code should produce the expected result.

```
library(reshape2)
merged_long <- melt(data=merged, 
               id.vars="Description", 
               variable.name="Month",
               value.name="RN")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to just use `melt(as.matrix(...))` given the nature of your data. Omit the `as.matrix` part if your data is already a `matrix`, obviously.

```
melt(as.matrix(mydf))
```

You can use `setNames` to rename the columns at the same time:

```
setNames(melt(as.matrix(mydf)), c("Description", "Month", "RN"))
#    Description Month   RN
# 1     2017 (A)   Jan 5980
# 2     2017 (P)   Jan 5762
# 3     2017 (A)   Feb 5341
# .........................
# .........................
# 23    2017 (A)   Dec 5356
# 24    2017 (P)   Dec 5630
```